Running 10,000 SELECT queries against SQLite takes hours
I am using Python and the sqlite3 lib to run around 10,000 SELECT queries against a single table. Running it locally on my not-high-spec-but-not-ancient laptop this is taking six or seven hours to complete. I created a composite index on the fields but that didn't make any difference. Here's the table and the query (the table is geolocation data for IP addresses, with the "addresses" being ints made by stripping the full stops):
CREATE TABLE ip2location (ip_from INT, ip_to INT, country_code VARCHAR(2), country_name VARCHAR(255), region_name VARCHAR(255), city_name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE INDEX `ix_ip_between` ON `ip2location`(`ip_from`, `ip_to`);

SELECT country_name, city_name FROM ip2location 
                    WHERE ip_from <= ? and ip_to >= ? 
                    AND country_name != '-';

query = "SELECT country_name, city_name FROM ip2location \
                    WHERE ip_from <= ? and ip_to >= ? \
                    AND country_name != '-';"
results = []
for ip in ips: 
    cur.execute(query, [ip, ip])
    result = cur.fetchone()
    if result:
        results.append(result)

I'd expect it to take a while but not this long. Does the problem lie with Python, SQLite, me? Thanks.
[EDIT] Looking at the query plan revealed that my index wasn't being used. I made separate indexes and that solves the problem. Thanks.

First, don't execute 10K queries. Find a way to rewrite your query so it only has to execute one query. The code you posted uses the same from and to IPs, so the query is equivalent to just WHERE IP_From=? and IP__From=IP_To. You can search for multiple IPs at once with WHERE IP_From IN (......). Second, the query searches for IPs and country_name, not just country_name. The SQL engine may decide there's no benefit to using the index, especially if the conditions aren't very selective.

Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. I don't know how I could rewrite it as one query though because I want to lookup individual IPs to match them with their country and city.

I already showed how. First, remove one of the parameters since it's identical to the other. In that case your query produces the same results as IP_From=? and IP_From=IP_To.  Then you can use WHERE IP_FROM IN (....) to batch 999 lookups at a time into only 1. You can use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN to see how SQLite executes the query and whether it used the index at all. I suspect that, given how the query is written, it doesn't

@PanagiotisKanavos, on this point, " The code you posted uses the same from and to IPs, so the query is equivalent to just...", ip_from and ip_to are lower and upper bounds indicating a region, down to city level.

Adding indexes for ip_to alone and maybe for country_name may help, too. The query plan will tell then if they really help.

@jaybee are you trying to find the IPs outside the range? In that case the index is useless because the expected results are potentially all rows. What are you trying to do?

Creating more indexes may not help because SQLite is a simple file-based embedded database, not a database server. It may not be able to use more than one index at a time. You'll have to test this with a database IDE and EXPLAIN. We can't guess the data distribution or what SQLite will decide to do just by looking at the query and indexes.

Work out your min and max IPs  and do one SELECT based on that range. Then navigate through the cursor (in Python) to handle the IPs you're interested in

just run one query inside sql as @panagiotis-kanavos suggested, and deal with country ~ ip relationship inside python code.
query = "SELECT country_name, city_name FROM ip2location \
                    WHERE ip_from <= ? and ip_to >= ? \
                    AND country_name != '-';"

here just input the smallest and biggest ip value inside your original ip list (as its type is int, it will always has a smallest and biggest value inside your ips).
after doing that, fetch rows or create a pandas dataframe based on your need (actually from your example code, i am not sure about what you want, if you just need distinct city name, then add it in the sql)
however, there is a risk that ip size is very large and you got a lot unneeded city name with a broaden ip range:
one solution is to filter after you get them back into python code, another solution may create a new column in table ip2location, which store hash value hi of pair of <ip_from, ip_to>.
With that column, you could directly use "in (h1, h2, ... )" in the query.

Try the below and see if there is any improvement.
Remove the index and add ip_to as a primary key.
Then query like below.
query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT country_name, city_name FROM ip2location \
                WHERE ip_to >= ? ORDER BY ip_to LIMIT 1) AS mytable \
                WHERE country_name != '-';"

Based on the example at https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/importing-ip2location-data-into-sqlite-and-querying-with-c-sharp-ipv4/.

Thanks, these are good suggestions. I added the LIMIT 1 and an index on ip_to, the query is now orders of magnitude faster.
